# How can I import facebook contacts to my Macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, contacts, facebook

This has been [a classic question but the answers have been outdated](https://www.lifewire.com/set-up-mac-integrate-with-facebook-2259916). I'm currently using Mojave. Adding facebook account to internet account group doesn't seem possible now. Does any one know how I can import my facebook contacts? I know iphone has an app called Sync but it requires paid membership.

Comment: please link the previous Questions you're referring to that are outdated.

Comment: @pkamb just added a link to an outdated solution